# How to write java script confirm popup box in spring MVC controller?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc

I am writing a file uploading program in spring mvc 3

> This is my controller class

```
        package com.fss;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;


@Controller
public class FileController {
 @Autowired
   ServletContext context; 
 private static final String PATH="D:\\fdirct";


 public int isDuplicate(String file) 
 {
     int i=0;
     File f = new File(PATH);
        String[] listOfFiles = f.list();

           for (int k = 0; k < listOfFiles.length; k++) {
                 if( file.equals(listOfFiles[k]))
                 {
                     i=1;
                 }
             } 
                 return i;
 }


@RequestMapping("/toupload")  
 public ModelAndView uploadFile(){
    return new ModelAndView("fileUpload"); 
 }  


//uploading if not existing file
 @RequestMapping(value="savefile",method=RequestMethod.POST)  
public ModelAndView uploadFile( @RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile file) throws Exception{ 

     int c=0;
     byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();  
     String filename = file.getOriginalFilename();
      String message =""; 
      String x="";

      if(file.isEmpty())
      {
          message="please select a file to upload ";
          ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView("fileUpload","message",message);
          return mav;

      }
      else 
      {
      //to check whether the file already exists
      c=isDuplicate(filename); 

      if(c==1)
      {
           x="crosscheck";
      }
      else if(c==0)
      {
          x="fileUpload";  
      }
      ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView(x);

      //if file already exists
           if(c==1)
           {
              bytes.toString();
              String filecontent=new String(bytes);

                 mav.addObject("filename",filename);
                 mav.addObject("filecontent",filecontent);
                 mav.addObject("1",c);
        message="File already exists !! Do you want me to overwrite it ?";

                }


           //if file doesn't exists
           else if(c==0)
           {
                 File f1=new File(PATH + File.separator + filename);
                 FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(f1);
                 BufferedOutputStream bos =new BufferedOutputStream(fos); 
                    bos.write(bytes);  
                    bos.flush();  
                    bos.close(); 
                    message="File successfully uploaded ";
           }
            mav.addObject("message", message);
            return mav;
      }

         }


 //crosschecking if exisitng file

 @RequestMapping(value="/saveagain",method = RequestMethod.POST)    
 public ModelAndView fileUploading2(@ModelAttribute("choice") Choice choice) throws IOException{

     String ch="";
     String m="";
     ch=choice.getChoice();
     if(ch.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
     {
         m="Upload suspended as requested by user ";
     }
     else if(ch.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
     {
        //System.out.println("In case of YES ");
         String filename=choice.getFname();
         String content=choice.getFcontent();

         File f1=new File(PATH+File.separator+filename);
         FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(f1);
         fw.write(content); 
         fw.close();
        m ="File successfully uploaded by overwriting the existing file !"; 
     }

    return new ModelAndView("crosscheck","m",m); 
 }
}
```

In above code, i am checking if the file being uploaded is an existing file. If not, i am uploading the file. If it is an existing file, i am redirecting the control to a jsp page, asking the user to overwrite the file , and collecting the user choice in a html form.

> jsp pages i used

fileUpload.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "form" uri = "http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
   <title>File Upload Example</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:powderblue;color:Tomato"> 
<br>
<br>
<center><form:form action="savefile" method = "POST" modelAttribute = "fileUpload"
         enctype = "multipart/form-data">
         Please select a file to upload : 
         <input type = "file" name = "file" /><br><br><br>
         <input type = "submit" value = "upload" />
         <input type = "reset" value = "Reset" />
      </form:form></center>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <center><b> ${message} </b></center>
      <br> 
     <center> <a href="view">View files</a><br><br>
       <a href="uploadxml">Upload xml as text file</a>  <br><br>
<a href="uploadcsv">Upload CSV as text file</a>  <br><br>
<a href="uploadxls">Upload excel as text file</a>  <br><br>
<a href="deletefiles">Delete multiple files</a>
   </center>
   </body>
</html>
```

> crosscheck.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:powderblue;color:Tomato">
<center><form method="POST" action="saveagain">    

   <center><h3>${message}(Say yes\no)</h3></center> 
   <br>

          <input type="text" name="choice">
            <br><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="fname" value="${filename}">

              <input type="hidden" name="fcontent" value="${filecontent}">
     <input type="submit" value="submit" /> </form></center>
<br>
<br>
<center><b>${m}</b></center>
<br><br>
<center><a href="toupload">Click me to upload a file</a>  <br><br>
<a href="uploadxml">Upload xml as text file</a>  <br><br>
<a href="uploadcsv">Upload CSV as text file</a>  <br><br>
<a href="uploadxls">Upload excel as text file</a>  <br><br>
<a href="view">View files</a><br><br>
<a href="deletefiles">Delete multiple files</a></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Instead of using a html form to know user's choice , how to use a javascript confirmation box ? In that if user selects OK, file should be overwritten else "Uploading suspended" message should be displayed. How and where to write the confirmation box ?

This is my bean class

```
  package com.fss;

    public class Choice {
    private boolean choice;
    private String fname;
    private String fcontent;

    public boolean isChoice() {
        return choice;
    }

    public void setChoice(boolean choice) {
        this.choice = choice;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getFcontent() {
        return fcontent;
    }

    public void setFcontent(String fcontent) {
        this.fcontent = fcontent;
    }


    }
```

I am including my jsp page.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script>
function getChoice(){
    var k=confirm("Do you want me to overwrite the existing file ?");
    return k;
}
</script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:powderblue;color:Tomato">
<center><form method="POST" action="saveagain">    
<h3>${message} </h3>
            <br> <br>
<input type="hidden" name="fname" value="${filename}">
<input type="hidden" name="fcontent" value="${filecontent}"> <br><br>
 <input type="button" value="Overwrite ?" onclick="choice=getChoice()"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit ?"></form></center>
<br>
<br>
<center><b>${m}</b></center>
<br><br>
<center><a href="toupload">Click me to upload a file</a>  <br><br>
<a href="uploadxml">Upload xml as text file</a>  <br><br>
<a href="uploadcsv">Upload CSV as text file</a>  <br><br>
<a href="uploadxls">Upload excel as text file</a>  <br><br>
<a href="view">View files</a><br><br>
<a href="deletefiles">Delete multiple files</a></center>
</body>
</html>
```

How to set the bean variable "choice" to the result of the Confirm popup ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function myFunction() {
    var a = confirm("Press a button!");
    console.log(a)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: Not sure where to place the suggested change in my code.

Comment: @sahithi var a has two values true or false create a if block and if a value is true call to your submit call

Comment: @Nishal Edu sorry nishal , still can't it.  1). whether the suggested change should be in jsp page or in controller ?  2) If it is in jsp page , how to take the return value of the function into a variable in controller ?